# How to pre populated some tag on ASPTokenInput

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tokenize

Hi I am using ASPTokenInput library find from below url
https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput/wiki
Can any one please help me how can I pre populate some token control on page load and on partial postback

Comment: they have a fully functional demo here https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput/downloads

Comment: Did you ever have the chance to try out the code I provided?  Or did you come up with an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had to tweak the code a bit, it looks like this feature wasn't fully tested in the original code.  I tried just adding items to "Items" and they showed up on page load, but would disappear immediately if I added a new item because they were not being stored in the hidden field.

After the code modifications you can do the following, where tiTest2 is an ASPTokenInput control (sorry, no tiTest2.Items.Add support):

```
            List<ASPTokenInput.Item> items = new List<ASPTokenInput.Item>();
            items.Add(new ASPTokenInputLib.ASPTokenInput.Item() { id = "United States", name = "United States" });
            items.Add(new ASPTokenInputLib.ASPTokenInput.Item() { id = "Brazil", name = "Brazil" });


            tiTest2.Items = items;
```

You'll need to change the code as follows:

```
   //Change the Items property to the following
   public List<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_hfPersist.Value)) return new List<Item>();

            else return (List<Item>)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<Item>>(_hfPersist.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            _hfPersist.Value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value); 
        }
    }

  //Empty out "OnLoad", so it looks like this.  The functionality it was providing we don't need anymore
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

    }
```